# Why is $sinx$ the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Most of us who are studying mathematics are familiar with the famous $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$. Why is it that we have $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$ and not $e^{ix}=sin(x)+icos(x)$? I haven't studied Complex Analysis to know the answer to this question. It pops up in Linear Algebra, Differential Equations, Multivariable Equations and many other fields. But I feel like textbooks and teachers just expect us students to take it as given without explaining it to a certain extent. I also couldn't find any good article that explains this.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html

Comment: Taylor-expand $\sin x$, $\cos x$, and $e^{ix}$. Then it will be clear.

Comment: You expect $e^0$ to be $i$?

Comment: Also thinking about when you graph complex numbers, you put imaginary numbers on the y-axis and real numbers on the x-axis

Comment: I feel like you guys don't know the answer to this question either to the point where you can explain it as if your explaining (intuitively) to a child. But I don't mean to offend anyone.

Comment: The best explanation I've seen goes that since the derivative of $e^{ix}$ is $ie^{ix}$, we have a curve which starts at $1$ and has a "velocity vector" always orthogonal to itself, pointing left, and of magnitude $1$. So naturally, it draws a circle. But I don't know how to make this rigorous.

Comment: @HansLundmark I don't see how the question I asked in any way resembles the one you put up as a duplicate.

Comment: Do you specifically want to know why the imaginary part *isn't* $\cos$?

Comment: Your question is "Why is $e^{ix} = \cos x+i\sin x$?" Hans's linked question is "How to prove that $e^{it} = \cos t+i\sin t$?" I don't see how you fail to see at least a passing resemblance.

Comment: Right. I was simply asking why its the $sinx$ portion that is lucky enough to be stuck with $i$ and not the $cosx$ portion. Nothing more. Maybe i'm not seeing something that is obvious.

Comment: @EamesCobb Do you at least understand why the trig functions turn up here in the first place?

Comment: @EamesCobb If the question is really: "I already understand that either $e^{iz} = \cos(z) + i \sin(z)$ or $e^{iz} = \sin(z) + i \cos(z)$. Which one is it and why?", then just plug in $z = 0$.

Comment: @EamesCobb: Obviously, if you understand why the formula looks like it does (i.e., if you know how to prove it), then you would understand why it doesn't look the other way. And if you look at the *answers* given here below, you will see that they are much the same as the answers to the old question...

Answer (score 2):

The way I make sense of it is to consider the McLaurin expansions of $e^{ix}$, $\cos(x)$, and $\sin(x)$.

Note:

$$e^{x} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{n!} = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots$$

$$\sin x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1} = x - \frac{x^3}{3!} + \frac{x^5}{5!} - \cdots$$

$$\cos x = \sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!} x^{2n} = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=ix$. Then the Maclaurin series of $e^{y}$ is:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
e^y=e^{ix}&=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^n}{n!}\\
&=& 1+ix-\frac{x^2}{2!}-i\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+i\frac{x^5}{5!}\ldots\\
&=& \Big(1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}-\ldots\Big)+i\Big(x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\ldots\Big)\\
&=& \Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\Big)+i\Big(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\Big)\\
&=&\cos x+i\sin x
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Hence $\sin x$ is the imaginary part of $e^{ix}$.

Comment: Not to be rude, but what does this add that wasn't contained in the other answer?

Comment: I had just signed up to stack exchange and this was my very first post, so I was just testing the markdown.